ROS2 rclpy subscription problem
I have a following problem: I am trying to subscribe two topic (image and pointcloud) and once the program detect falling edge from gpio pins it should publish the image and point cloud. However the program does not behave correcly since after some while the program stops subscribing ether image or point cloud topic or both.
I am using jetson xavier agx and ros2 foxy.
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import Jetson.GPIO as GPIO
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, PointCloud2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor, SingleThreadedExecutor
from rclpy.callback_groups import MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup, ReentrantCallbackGroup
class ZedCapture(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('zed_capture_node')
        # Pin Setup:
        self.input_pin = 18
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  # 
        GPIO.setup(self.input_pin, GPIO.IN)  # set pin as an input pin
        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.input_pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.gpio_callback, polltime=0.2)
        img_callback_group1 = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        pc_callback_group1 = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        self.img_subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, '/zed2/zed_node/rgb/image_rect_color', self.img_callback,1,callback_group=img_callback_group1) # Image subscription
        self.pc_subscription = self.create_subscription(PointCloud2, '/zed2/zed_node/point_cloud/cloud_registered', self.pc_callback,1,callback_group=pc_callback_group1)  # Point cloud subscription
        self.img_subscription
        self.pc_subscription
        self.img_publisher = self.create_publisher(Image, '/zed_image_capture', 1)
        self.pc_publisher = self.create_publisher(PointCloud2, '/zed_pc_capture', 1)
        self.image = None
        self.pointcloud = None
        
        
    def gpio_callback(self, channel):
        #if self.image is not None and self.pointcloud is not None:
        self.get_logger().info('Button pressed. save the data and publish topics')
        print("Image timestamp in gpio_callback:", self.image.header.stamp)
        self.img_publisher.publish(self.image)
        self.pc_publisher.publish(self.pointcloud)

    def img_callback(self, msg):
        print("Image1 timestamp in img callback:", msg.header.stamp)
        self.image = msg
        #self.get_logger().info('Subscribed image1')

    def pc_callback(self, msg):
        print("Pc1 timestamp in img callback:", msg.header.stamp)
        self.pointcloud = msg
        #self.get_logger().info('Subscribed pc1')



def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = ZedCapture()
    # Call the spin_node method of the node instance to start processing events in a loop
    #node.spin_node()
    #rclpy.spin(node)
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(node)
    executor.spin();
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

